# civiCase emails don't use case tokens?? Print/merge does? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: email, civicase

I have templates that use a range of tokens from the contact and the case, including standard case tokens and custom fields.  i.e.

{contact.display_name}   {case.id}   {case.subject}   {case.custom_154}

The case tokens are not processed when sending an email (via email activity)

They are processed on print/merge document.  (via print/merge document activity)

Is this by design?

Answer (score 2):

When sending email via email activity only contact tokens are supported. If you have [Civicase token extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicase-tokens) installed and enabled than you can pass `caseid=34` (where 34 is case id) in activity email url

```
eg http://example.org/civicrm/activity/email/add?atype=3&action=add&reset=1&context=standalone&caseid=34
```

Comment: Yes, the token extension adds about 4 fields, but not the whole case columns, nor any extended case data.

Answer (score 1):

They work if you use the email icon in the roles section on manage case to initiate the email. They don't work if you use Contacts -> New Email from the general menu since it won't know what case it is.

Comment: I'm talking about emails sent from within the case - where it does not work - not even coded.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm really not sure why this has not been done.  It was a handful of lines changed in 2 files to make this work.

It was so easy I'm concerned I'm missing something about why it was not setup in the first place.

the main change is in CRM/activity/BAO/activity.php  which needs an extra argument to pass the case ID and then a few extra lines to for replaceCaseTokens().   Case_ID needs passing from messagetemplate.

If anyone needs this they can DM me for the details, its in test now.

Comment: What version are you on? See also https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16105

Comment: Excellent.   I'll pick this up.